# Parse hashtags between symbols

Tags: java, android

I need to parse hashtags from String (`test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa`).

```
String text = "test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa";
String[] words = text.split(" ");
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( final String word : words) {
    if (word.substring(0, 1).equals("@")) {
        tags.add(word);
    }
}
```

In the end i need an Array with `"@georgios" , "@gsabanti" , "@afa"` elements.
But now `@georgios@gsabanti` showing like one hashtag.

How to fix it?

Comment: use regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for the Regular Expressions:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(@[^@\\s]*)")
                         .matcher("test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa");

List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    tags.add(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(tags);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reqular expressions! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of doing that

```
    String text = "test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa";
    String patternst = "@[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternst);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tags.add(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: @Nikolay: You may want to consider adding `A-Z` and also maybe `0-9` to `patternstr` if real-world users work with them for a better user experience.

Comment: @Nikolay Edited. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Arraylist instead of array:

```
String text = "test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa";
ArrayList<String> hashTags = new ArrayList()<>;

char[] c = text.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++) {
if(c[i]=='@') {
    String hash = "";
    for(int j=i+1;j<c.length;j++) {
      if(c[j]==' ' || c[j]=='@') {
        hashTags.add(hash);
        hash="";
        break;
      }
      hash+=c[j];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa";
String[] words = text.split("(?=@)|\\s+")
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( final String word : words) {
    if (!word.isEmpty() && word.startsWith("@")) {
        tags.add(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string at " " or "@" and keep the delimiters and filter those out which start with "@" like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    String text = "test comment @georgios@gsabanti sefse @afa";
    String[] tags = Stream.of(text.split("(?=@)|(?= )")).filter(e->e.startsWith("@")).toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tags));
}
```